# Using a foreach inside an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use codeigniter's active record class to fetch a value from the database that i need to insert to a table with this code

```
$q = $this->db->get('center_number');
$cd = $this->db->get('running_tasks');`

$ask_for_permission = array(
    'messagefrom' => $le_message_from,
    'messageto' => foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
        $row->center_number;
    },
    'messagetext' => 'The dataset'. '' .foreach ($cd->result() as $row)
    {
        $row->task_name;
    }. ' is requesting permission to credit the account.Reply with yes to allow or no to decline.Anything else other than yes or no shall be ignored.'
);
```

I get the error:

```
unexpected 'foreach'
```

How can I fetch the record from the database from within `$ask_for_permission` array?.

Comment: It's not the way you populate an array...

Comment: simply does not make sense

Comment: You can’t use `foreach` in that place. Either gather the data in an array beforehand, and assign that to the `messageto` key, or populate `messageto` in a loop afterwards.

Comment: Please give a sample of the result you want to acheive

Comment: From the active record docs https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 0):

```
// First Generate the Array
$ask_for_permission = array(
   'messagefrom' => $le_message_from,
   'messageto' => '',
   'messagetext' => 'The dataset'. '' .foreach ($cd->result() as $row)
                    {
                    $row->task_name;
                    }. ' is requesting permission to credit the account.Reply with yes to allow or no to  
                    decline.Anything else other than yes or no shall be ignored.'
    );

// Second, populate it with all values of the $q->result() array
foreach ($q->result() as $row)
                    {
                    $ask_for_permission['messageto'] .= $row->center_number;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function msgTo() {
    $str = '' ;
    foreach ($r->result() as $row) {
        $str .= $row;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

and replace your foreach with msgTo()

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
    $q = $this->db->get('center_number');

    $le_message_from = '08009898';
    $ask_for_permission = array(
   'messagefrom' => $le_message_from,
   'messageto' => $q->row->center_number,           
   'messagetext' => 'The dataset'. ' '. $this->db->query("select task_name from running_tasks limit 1")->row()->task_name .' '.'is requesting permission to credit the account.Reply with yes to allow or no to  
                    decline.Anything else other than yes or no shall be ignored.'
    );

    $this->db->insert('messageout', $ask_for_permission);
```